# How to use timestamp from perl in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, perl, timestamp, utc, epoch

In my backend (written in Perl), I generate an end date. In the front end, I want to compute the remaining time before this end date. To avoid time zones problems, I want to use UTC

In perl, the end date is encapsulated in a `data` object:

```
data => {endTime => $date->epoch()}
```

And this is the Java Script function that I've written:

```
    updateCounter: function (element){
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        var endTime = $(element).data("endtime");
        var diff = epochEndDealTime - milliseconds;
        console (diff, now, endTime);
        ...
    }
```

I know for a fact that `endTime` is in the future, so `diff` should be positive, but when I test it is smaller, e.g.:

```
-1530397503497 1531929432906 1531929409
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your epoch seems to be in seconds not milliseconds

Comment: @charlietfl That could be a reason, but still `now/1000 > endTime`

Comment: After dividing could be timezone offset issue now if dates are close (within hours)

Comment: @charlietfl Could you please explain this a little bit more? I thought that this UTC was an universal solution exactly to avoid this kind of problems

Comment: Btw by using [this](https://www.epochconverter.com/) I see that in GMT the bigger one is 3:57:12.906 PM while the other one is 4:17:14 PM, so to me it's not a matter of hours, but minutes too

Comment: Re "*I want to use UTC*", You're not using UTC date-time --you're not using a date-time at all-- but epoch timestamps will do perfectly fine too.

Comment: Assuming that the line below your code is output from `console.log`, `endTime` should be `1531929409`, right?

Comment: Are you sure your Perl is calculating a timestamp that is in the future? Your example looks more like it's "now" as it's only a few (23) seconds different from the timestamp Javascript is giving.

Answer (score 2):

If we organize the numbers differently

```
now:     1531929432906 
endTime: 1531929409
```

you might notice `now` is roughly 1000x larger than `endTime`. That's because JS's `new Date().getTime()` returns the number of *milliseconds* since `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`, while Perl's `time` returns the number of *seconds* since `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`.

So, simply multiply `endTime` by 1000, or divide `now` by 1000.

(You could also use different means of obtaining the time in Perl to obtain more precision, but that doesn't appear to be needed.)